# Task of struct blk_major_name *next in structure struct blk_major_name { } in Linux block driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to learn about the Linux block driver from https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/block_device_drivers.html

I looked in the background code of `register_blkdev()` function and came across

```
struct blk_major_name{
    struct blk_major_name *next;
    int major;
    char name[16];
} *major_names[BLKDEV_MAJOR_HASH_SIZE];
```

I understood from the code of `register_blkdev()` that:

```
major = major number of block driver, same as index of array `major_names`

name = name of block driver
```

but I cannot understand use of next in above struct.

This seems similar to a linked list node but I'm not sure. Please help. And please feel free to correct me if above information is not correct.

Comment: Please format your (next) questions with markup, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

The major device number is not necessarily the same as the `major_names` index. The index is in the range [0, 254] ([0, `BLKDEV_MAJOR_HASH_SIZE-1`]), but the major device number is in the range [1, 511] ([0, `BLKDEV_MAJOR_MAX-1`]). The major device number is hashed to an index by `index = major_to_index(major);` which is equivalent to `index = major % BLKDEV_MAJOR_HASH_SIZE;`.

More than one major device number can map to the same index. Major device numbers 1, 256 and 511 all map to `major_names` index 1. (Three major device numbers mapping to index 1 is the worst case. All indices other than 1 are mapped to by two major device numbers.)

The `next` member of `struct blk_major_name` is needed to search through all the registered major device numbers that map to the same `major_names` index.

Index numbers 1 to 254 are mapped to by the identical major device number. The code that allocates an unused major device number in the range [1, 254] when `register_blkdev` is called with major number 0 does so by looking for an index in the the range [1, 254] that has not been allocated. There is room for improvement in the code that allocates an unused major number (at least up to and including the latest kernel version 5.10 at the time of writing) because it is only checking for unused indices. For example, if major number 254 has not been registered, but major number 509 has been registered, then since both major numbers map to the same index 254, major number 254 will not be allocated dynamically in this case, even though it is available.